# Странное поведение Dictionary

Tags: c#, словари

Создал два словаря. Главный (gDic) и буферный `dic2`.

```
Dictionary<string,List<string>> dic2 = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string,List<string>>> gDic = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<string>>>();
```

Когда я добавляю элементы в `gDic` и потом очищаю `dic2`, то и в `gDic` они пропадают

```
gDic.Add("Значение",dic2)
```

Пробовал даже создать еще одну буферную переменную `buff`. Думал что после этого изменится ситуация.

```
var buff = dic2;
gDic.Add("Значение",buff)
```

Comment: все дело в том, что добавляете вы ссылку, поэтому `dic2` и элемент в главном словаре ссылаются на один и тот же объект и когда удаляете элементы из одного - удаляются отовсюду. Для решения - не очищайте `dic2` - а просто присваивайте ему новый экземпляр: `dic2 = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();`

Comment: спасибо)!юююююю

Comment: @Grundy преобразуйте свой комментарий в ответ, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так как `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` ссылочный тип, то выполняя

```
gDic.Add("Значение",dic2)
```

в словарь добавляется ссылка, поэтому dic2 и элемент в главном словаре ссылаются на один и тот же объект и когда удаляете элементы из одного - удаляются отовсюду.

Для решения, не очищайте `dic2`, а просто присваивайте ему новый экземпляр:

```
dic2 = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
```