# Поведение Dictionary при объявлении списка

Tags: c#, словари

Написал вот такой вот код:

```
  private void setCombineQuerys()
    {
        Dictionary<string, Action> temp = new Dictionary<string, Action>();
        temp.Add("Проверка на категорию", checkCategoryClass);
        temp.Add("Проверка на тип документа", checkPassport);
        temp.Add("Проверка на активный результат", checkActiveResult);
        temp.Add("Проверка на УКП", checkParticipantsUKP);
        temp.Add("Проверка на ОВЗ", checkParticipantsOVZ);
        Category Participants = new Category("Участники", true, temp, queryForParticipants);
        ListA.Add(Participants);

        temp.Clear();
        temp.Add("Проверка на телефон", checkMobilePhone);
        temp.Add("Проверка на почту", checkEmail);
        temp.Add("Проверка на код работника", checkWorkerCode);
        temp.Add("Проверка на код станционарный телефон", checkStaticPhone);
        temp.Add("Проверка на специализацию", checkParticipantSpecialization);
        temp.Add("Проверка на прикрепление к ппэ", checkParticipantPP);
        temp.Add("Проверка на категорию", checkParticipantCategory);
        Category Workers = new Category("Работники", false, temp, "");/*Заменить запрос*/
        ListB.Add(Workers);
    }
```

И вроде бы в итоге должно быть два экземпляра класса Category: Participants с 5 элементами проверок и Workers с 7 элементами, но, когда я обращаюсь к первому, то получаю в ответ 7 элементов Category Workers.

Объясните мне, почему так происходит? Прогнал по шагам:
 1. Создаётся нулевой temp
 2. Заполняется пятью экземплярами
 2. Создаётся Participants и заполняется пятёркой temp
 3. Очищается temp методом Clear() и у Participants значение temp становится нулевым.
 4. temp заполняется семью экземплярами
 5. Создаётся Workers и заполняется семёркой temp. Participants в этот момент также заполняется этой семёркой. 
Это свойство Dictionary и метода Clear?

Класс Category:

```
public class Category{
             private string name;
             private bool bD;
             private string query;
             private Dictionary<string, Action> methods;

             public string Name { get => name; set => name = value; }
             public bool BD { get => bD; set => bD = value; }
             public string Query { get => query; set => query = value; }
             public Dictionary<string, Action> Methods { get => methods; set => methods = value; }

             public Category(string name, bool bd, Dictionary<string,Action> methods, string query)
             {
                 this.Name = name;
                 this.BD = bd;
                 this.Query = query;
                 this.Methods = methods;    
              } 
        }
```

Comment: У вас один и тот же словарь в двух категориях...

Comment: Нашёл ответ сразу после того, как задал вопрос - "гений"

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary ссылочный контейнер, поэтому после очищения ссылки обновляются в обоих списках

[Странное поведение Dictionary](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/478438)

Comment: Тогда вопрос по ссылке - дубликат вашего вопроса.